# I want to remove leading spaces in a numeric cell in MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I want to remove leading spaces in a numeric cell in MS Excel e.g i have a value {'       169,207.00} which i want to convert into numeric as {169,207.00}, Please guide me which excel formula is helpful for me.

Answer (score 3):

PeterH's answer of `=TRIM(A1)+0` should have worked. 
A couple other variations that should work are

- `=A1+0`
- `=VALUE(A1)`

Comment: +1 for Value, rarely see this used

Answer (score 2):

see formula i used as you used in your formula:
[image]

Comment: All of the answers posted to this question as of 5/25/23 yield that #VALUE! error for me. trim() does not remove the spaces, and so the number remains in a text form. value() and attempts to add 0 or any other mathematical operation all yield #VALUE!. Perhaps there are special spaces that trim() and other Excel text to number functions don't recognize as spaces.

Comment: On further checking, that was indeed the problem (the "spaces" weren't really spaces). I posted a separate answer to convert the non-space, but space-like characters to traditional spaces. Then these other approaches work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TRIM` for this. I.E `=TRIM(A1)`

`TRIM` will remove all trailing and leading spaces from a text value.

More detail can be found here:

https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-trim-function

To turn a text value into numeric you can simply add a 0.

I.E `=TRIM(A1)+0` will turn '       169,207.00 into 169207, you can then format to your desired output.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the formula below:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")
```

Comment: this formula is not working

Answer (score 0):

If the other methods here don't work, it may be that you have special spaces in the cell before (or after) the number. This can happen if you copied from a Word table with hard (non-breaking) spaces or other methods. These are frequently used when editing a table in Word, because they are one of the easiest ways to achieve the desired formatting, just pressing Ctrl+Shift+Space in Word (doesn't create them in Excel). The value() and other mathematical operations can only work with numbers and standard typed spaces.

You can test if this is the problem by using:

```
=CODE(LEFT(A1,1))
```

Where A1 would be the cell you want to test and this assumes leading spaces (if trailing, replace LEFT with RIGHT).

If these are normal spaces, it will return 32, the ASCII code for a space.

In my case, the spaces had an ASCII code of 160, which is a non-breaking space.

In this case, you can fix all of these by:

1. Copy the character (just edit the cell, and select the space-like
   character and copy it
2. Press Ctrl+H (search and replace)
3. Paste the character in the search box, meaning it will search for the space-like character
4. Type a regular space in the replace box, meaning it will replace the space-like character with a traditional space
5. Hit Replace all

Now the other solutions on this page will work.